# Loop specific line(s) in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have this iMacros script. All i need is a way, i supose Javascript, to replay the last 3 lines for 10 times.

```
URL GOTO=http://mywebsite.here.com/

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 5); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Get<SP>a<SP>random<SP>post!
```

I need it to go to my url once, and wait for random seconds and click the button 10 times.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I suggest trying the following macro:

```
SET url EVAL("({{!LOOP}} == 1) ? 'http://mywebsite.here.com/' : 'STAY ON THIS PAGE';")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO={{url}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 5); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Get<SP>a<SP>random<SP>post!
```

Play it in loop mode with the 'Max:' value set to 10.

Comment: The logic is correct, but the problem is that after the first loop, it tries to navigate to "STAY ON THIS PAGE" (like it was a url)

Comment: For this issue I placed the `!ERRORIGNORE` variable and tested the code in 'iMacros for Firefox'. No problems occured. Anyway try to substitute 'STAY ON THIS PAGE' for 'javascript: undefined;' .

Comment: In Chrome it tries to navigate to that "page". Let me try in Firefox.

Comment: 'javascript: undefined' must be OK in Chrome!

Comment: Works like a charm. It seems Chrome has some issues with it. Thank you so much!